# extracting wikipedia links, regex

Tags: python, regex

I am a novice programmer and have problem with regex.
I have big file with posts and i want to extract wikipedia links.

for now i have this regex:

```
wiki = 'http[s]?://([a-zA-Z.0-9]{,3}wikipedia.org/wiki/[/!@i^*$a-zA-Z0-9_()-]*)(?:&quot)?'
```

it works fine but sometimes have results like:

```
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)
```

how to change my regex to not fetch a closing parenthesis if there wasn't an opening parenthesis

Comment: Consider using XPath for this task, regex can do a lot, but xpath is real specialist on values form XML documents. Python also provides `urlparse`, which could help you in parsing parts of the urls.

Comment: Why are only strings that begin with `http` considered links in Wikipedia?

Comment: Can you provide sample data please

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the parentheses from the regex, then add a variant with both an open and a close parenthesis. Theoretically you could need two or more, but I don't think Wikipedia allows more than one pair in titles.

```
wiki1 = 'http[s]?://([a-zA-Z.0-9]{,3}wikipedia.org/wiki/[/!@i^*$a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?:&quot)?'
wiki2 = 'http[s]?://([a-zA-Z.0-9]{,3}wikipedia.org/wiki/[/!@i^*$a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\([/!@i^*$a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\)[/!@i^*$a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(?:&quot)?'
wiki = wiki1 + '|' + wiki2
```

Comment: No catches links such as :      en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)

Comment: You really have no way of determining whether a link should or should not have a trailing parenthesis if you're simply given a plain string (short of testing the link you've extracted). There are conventions where you would have proper matching parantheses, but there's nothing stopping me from putting random `)`'s in my article titles. If you're parsing `href` attributes that's a different story, but I'm assuming that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing forbids to build an url that contains unbalanced or nested parenthesis (a case that can't be solved with the `re` module, but can be solved with the `regex` module). However, since you are looking for wikipedia urls, you can assume that you will not find this kind of format, but only urls with a single level of balanced parenthesis, like: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)`.

The idea is simple, adapt your pattern to allow parenthesis only in this context (1 level, balanced):

```
wiki = r"""(?ix)                       # case insensitive & verbose mode
    https?://                          # perhaps you should make this optional?
    (
        [a-z0-9.]{,3}                  # 
        wikipedia.org/wiki/
        (?:
            [/!@i^*$a-z0-9_-]+         # part without parenthesis
          |                            # OR
            [(] [/!@i^*$a-z0-9_-]+ [)] # part between parenthesis
        )*                             # repeat the group 0 or more times
    )"""
```

*Note: I have removed `(?:&quote)?` that doesn't seem useful, but you can put it if you need it. In this case you must change the line `[/!@i^*$a-z0-9_-]+` (part without parenthesis) with `(?=([/!@i^*$a-z0-9_-]+))\2` to [emulate an atomic group](http://instanceof.me/post/52245507631/regex-emulate-atomic-grouping-with-lookahead) and prevent [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).*